# send packet to UBX protocol

Tags: c++, gps

lately I have been working on a GPS reciever that supports both UBX and NEMA protocols. I am using serial programing on C++. I am trying to use UBX protocol, but it seems that I only recieve from NEMA. I downloaded the driver and I think I need to send a package first to recieve through UBX. Does anyone know a link or could tell me how could I send these packages the method  I developed is stated below I think I need a small command before I start reading the data. Please someone help me here :D

```
void read_port(void)
{
    unsigned char c='D';


     while (c!='q')
    {
            if (read(fd, UBX_buffer, sizeof(UBX_buffer))>0)      
            {
                data = read(fd, UBX_buffer, sizeof(UBX_buffer));

            //  write(fd,&UBX_buffer,1);  // if new data is available on the serial port, print it out

      cout<<"Data on the port =  ";
      for (unsigned i =0; i< sizeof(UBX_buffer) ;i++){
        cout<<&UBX_buffer[i];  


    }
    cout<<" "<<endl;
     for (int i=0; i<fd; i++)  // Process bytes received
{

     switch(UBX_step)     //we start from zero and increment as we go through the cases
  {
  case 0:  
    if(data==0xB5)  UBX_step++;  break; // UBX sync char 1 //check for the first data packet and go to next byte


  case 1:  if(data==0x62) UBX_step++;// UBX sync char 2 //check for the second data packet and go to the next byte

    else    UBX_step=0; break;  //if first and second packets are not correct then go back and check again     

  case 2:   UBX_class=data; checksum(UBX_class); UBX_step++;  break;

  case 3:   UBX_id=data;  checksum(UBX_id);  UBX_step++; break;

  case 4:   UBX_payload_length_hi=data; checksum(UBX_payload_length_hi);  UBX_step++;  break;

  case 5:   UBX_payload_length_lo=data; checksum(UBX_payload_length_lo);  UBX_step++; break;

  case 6:         // Payload data read...
  if (UBX_payload_counter < UBX_payload_length_hi)  // We stay in this state until we reach the payload_length
    {
      UBX_buffer[UBX_payload_counter] = data;
      checksum(data);
      UBX_payload_counter++;
    }
    else
      UBX_step++; 
    break;
  case 7:   ck_a=data;  UBX_step++; break;      // First checksum byte
  case 8:   ck_b=data;                           // Second checksum byte

    // We end the GPS read...

    if((ck_a= ck_a)&&(ck_b= ck_a))   // Verify the received checksum with the generated checksum.. 
          parse_ubx_gps();               // Parse new GPS packet...


    UBX_step=0;
    UBX_payload_counter=0;
    ck_a=0;
    ck_b=0;
    GPS_timer=0; //Restarting timer...
    break;
      }
  }

            if (read(STDIN_FILENO,&c,1)>0) write(fd,&c,1);  // if new data is available on the console, send it to the serial port

    }

    close(fd);



  } // End Switch
} // End For
```

Answer (score 0):

At the ublox Homepage you can Download the ublox protocoll specification. There, look at the cfg messages. For test purposes, you also can enable the ubx protocol via the tool `u-Center`.